# Object Oriented Design concerning inheritance in Python

Tags: python, oop

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

    def add_score(self, score):
        self.score = self.score + score



class HumanPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self, name="Human")


class ComputerPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self):
        Player.__init__(self, name="Eliza")


class Score:

    def __init__(self, human, computer):
        self.human = human
        self.computer = computer

    def add_score(self, player, score):
        self.player.add_score(score)
```

My problem is with the `add_score` method in the `Score` class.

**In Python context:**

Since both `human` and `computer` are inherited from the `Player` class (they have their own methods, but omitted in this question), how can I refer either of them in the `add_score` method? (To be clear: I want to say `add_score` to any object inherited from the `Player` class. [Does it matter if meant “`add_score` to any object either from the `Player` class or to any object inherited from the `Player` class”?])

Comment: Do you want to add the tag which stands for the language used ?

Comment: For 1, are you talking about referencing the members of `human` and `computer` in your `score` class or the classes of `human` and `computer`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're using python in your example and so there are a few answers to this question. There is the OOP way of doing this and then there is the pythonic way of doing this.

The OOP way of doing this is that your `__str__` (python's version of `ToString`) would be abstract (or otherwise implemented generically) and you'd override that in the derived class. Though, truthfully, you'd not use `ToString` -- you'd define an abstract method for this purpose specifically. Perhaps `PrintScore`.

That said, your usage of OOP in this example isn't great either. Does the `ComputerPlayer` and `HumanPlayer` have different implementations resulting in the need of derived classes? Given your example (and perhaps you have plans for more), you don't. You could just use a `Player` Class and make a property "`IsAI`". Set that for true for a computer player and false for human player.

*I don't mean for this to sound critical so please don't take it that way. I simply mean to provide some guidance.*